# Differential of a $SO(3)$ elements using differentiable manifold formalisms

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential

If $M$, $N$ are smooth manifolds, $p \in M$ and $X_p \in T_p M$ and $F$ a smooth map from $M$ to $N$ the definition of the differential of $F$ at $p$ is given by the equality

$$
F_{*,p}(X_p) f = X_p(f \circ F) , \;\; \forall f\in C^{\infty}(N)
$$

It's easy to show that $F_{*,p}$ is a linear map.

I was trying to figure what the differential is in the following example... Let $R^z(\phi)$ defined as

$$
R^z(\phi) = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
\cos\phi & -\sin(\phi) & 0 \\ 
\sin\phi & \cos(\phi) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

We can regard this rotation matrix as a map $R^z(\cdot) : [0,2\pi] \to SO(3)$.

My question is... what's the differential in this case, in local coordinates at least, I was trying to use the definition

$$
R^z_{*,\phi_0}(X_{\phi_0})f = X_{\phi_0}(f \circ R^z)
$$

but I got stuck, and the reason is because I'm dealing with a matrix, I think what I should end up with is the componentwise derivative of the matrix, but I'd like to show that.

Also I'd like to generalize this to general element of $SO(3)$, using euler angles representation.

My background is [Tu's Introduction to manifolds](http://im0.p.lodz.pl/~kubarski/AnalizaIV/Wyklady/L-Tu-1441973990.pdf).

Can you help?

Comment: $SO(3)$ is 3-dimensional so there's no way you get a whole $3\times3$ matrix as differential. Instead the differential is $3\times1$, and its local representation depends on the charts you use for $SO(3)$.

Comment: If the function was from a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ to a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ I think the differential could be worked out. I don't see the implication you mentioning (i.e. dimension implies there's no 3x3 differential). Can you please elaborate a bit more on the chart part?

Comment: I think you're confusing where your map $R^z$ ends up. If it's a map into **all $3\times3$ matrices**, then you're right to take the componentwise derivative. If it's a map into $SO(3)$, then you need to work locally with a chart for $SO(3)$. Any smooth map from $M^m$ to $N^n$ has a local representation as a map from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, and the differential there is an $n\times m$ matrix.

Comment: I think if you give me a complete answer would really help me, including chart and everything. I think I have a gap between the definition and how to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

You can see, $SO(3)$ has a subset of the vector space of $3\times 3$ matrices. The differential of $R(\phi)$ is 
$\pmatrix{-sin(\phi)&-cos(\phi)&0\cr cos(\phi)&-sin(\phi)&0\cr 0&0&0}$

Comment: As I mentioned in my question I guessed that was the expression. My question is how do you get that from the definition I've written.

Comment: This is a bad answer, because the OP has explicitly stated they're looking at this as a map into $SO(3)$.